# A term similar to "typography", "paragraph" or something else that improves the readability of written language

Tags: word-request

I [suggested this modification](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/102613)(improvement) to a post, though I don't know the term/expression to refer to this kind of modification.

[image]

I [said the following](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/243235/109190) to suggest an answerer do something like above

> How about having the answer in a good paragraph?

and got the response

> A paragraph denotes a change of emphasis.

Obviously, I didn't express my suggestion clearly. That's why I'd like to know that term.

I googled a bit and got some hits, e.g. "typography", "typographic design", some of those look like font design which is not what I want either.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe "layout" or "format".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all falls under *[formatting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/formatting)*, and indeed that is the wording that the Help Center uses:

> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thank you. Is it too much for some answerers who is not familiar with Markdown or HTML? This is English Learner sites, some answerers is not necessarily a software engineer, right?

Comment: But you were just asking about vocabulary suggestions, weren't you?

Comment: @WXJ96163 It can be hard to keep track of what symbols do what, but the toolbar makes that mostly unnecessary. Also being a programmer doesn’t mean you know how to format because I see formatting mistakes all the time on Stack Overflow :p